# How to access user object in Django Djoser token serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have the following in settings:

```
DJOSER = {
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'token': 'api.api.MyTokenSerializer'
    }
}
```

And here is that serializer, used for login:

```
class MyTokenSerializer(TokenSerializer):
    auth_token = serializers.CharField(source="key")
    registration_complete = serializers.BooleanField(source="user.registration_complete", read_only=True)
    app_mode = serializers.CharField(source="user.app_mode", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = djoser_settings.TOKEN_MODEL
        fields = ("auth_token", "profile_complete", "app_mode")
```

and now I need to add one more field, but that field is a method field and it needs the `user` object.

In pseudocode:

```
class MyTokenSerializer(TokenSerializer):
    ...
    new_field = my_method(user_object)

    ...
```

But I don't understand how to access the user object in this serializer. I see that the `user` object is used as a source in two fields (`registration_complete` and `app_mode`) but I don't know how to access it directly in order to pass it to the method. Is it possible to access the `user` object here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

> This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on the serializer class it is attached to.

This method takes in parameter the object which is serialized. In your case, it's a `djoser_settings.TOKEN_MODEL` ([which by default is `rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token`](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#token-model)).

If you look at the [implementation of this model](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py), you'll see that there is a foreign key pointing to the user. That's why you can do things like `source=user.registration_complete` ([`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) is actually a convenient shortcut to serialize fields in foreign objects).

So you can do something like this:

```py
class MyTokenSerializer(TokenSerializer):
    new_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_new_field(self, obj):
        # "obj" is a Token object
        user = obj.user

        # Return the value you want
        return f'Hello {user.email}'
```